Why the term "geometric rough paths".
I wanted to understand where the term "geometric rough paths" comes from, and when was it used for the first time. In this MathOverflow post, Martin Hairer suggests that the term geometric comes from the fact that solutions of controlled differential equations driven by geometric rough paths transform according to the usual chain rule. That said, I wanted to see if anyone has a different idea about the term "geometric". Thanks.
--- Edit ---
In "Differential equations driven by rough signals" by Terry Lyons, the author says a multiplicative functional is "geometric" if it takes its values in the group-like elements. Still, this doesn't provide much insight on why the term "geometric" is being used. So, besides the interpretation linked above, I'd appreciate any additional insights.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Lyons_(mathematician)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207701/why-the-term-geometric-rough-path

I literally included in my post a link to that post. Also, not sure how a link to Terry Lyons' wikipedia page is supposed to help.

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path claims that "Terry Lyons developed what is now known as the theory of rough paths" , so Terry Lyons may know why it was named "rough path". It was not very clear earlier that you were asking why "geometric" was additionally used.

Apologies, but yes the question is more about the "geometric" part of the name. The "rough paths" part is evident.

AFAIK the geometric part of the name refers to equations on manifolds. Satisfying the usual rules of calculus means that solutions will transform as expected under change of coordinates, thus preserving the geometry of the manifold. This has been studied in the 80s by Eméry, Meyer, Schwartz, etc (before rough paths). Stratonovich diferential equations (geometric) can be defined on any manifold, but Itô equations (non-geometric) require a connection and some additional assumptions to transform correctly.
